Is the function $t \mapsto \mathbb P \left (\left |X - Y \right | > t\ |\ (X + Y) > t \right )$ monotone on $(0, \infty)\ $?

Let $X, Y$ be iid random variables following $\mathcal N (0,1).$ Consider the function $g : (0, \infty) \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $$g(t) = \mathbb P \left (\left |X - Y \right | > t\ |\ (X + Y) > t \right )$$
$t \in (0, \infty).$ Is $g$ monotone on $(0, \infty)\ $?

Since $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, it follows from symmetry that for all $t \in (0, \infty),$ $$\begin{align*} g(t) & = 2\ \mathbb P \left (\left (X - Y \right ) > t\ |\ (X + Y) > t \right ) \\ & =  \frac {2\ \mathbb P \left (\left (X - Y \right ) > t,\ (X + Y) > t \right )} {\mathbb P \left (\left (X + Y \right ) > t \right )}. \end{align*}$$
It seems like I need to use convolutions to get an expression for the denominator. How should I tackle the numerator? I feel like since $Y$ and $-Y$ are identically distributed the ratio is just $2,$ although I am not quite sure about that. Any suggestion in this regard would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks for your valuable time.

It is well known that if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ then $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ are independent normal variables. So $g(t)=P(|X-Y|>t)$. Further, $Z=\frac {X-Y }{\sqrt 2}$ is $N(0,1)$ too. So $g(t)=P(|Z|>t\sqrt 2)$ which is decreasing.
Note: One easy way of showing that $\frac {X-Y} {\sqrt 2}$ and $\frac {X+Y} {\sqrt 2}$ are also i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ is to use charactersitic functions.
